# Причастный оборот, где опущено главное слово

Tags: причастия, причастный-оборот

Мой товарищ написал следующее предложение, перепутав, по его словам, причастие с деепричастием. Как следствие, он поставил лишние запятые. Однако одна моя знакомая утверждает, что после слова "теперь" может стоять главное слово "люди" — оно просто опущено, поэтому запятые стоят верно.

Рассудите, пожалуйста. Нужны ли тут запятые, а если нужны, то по какому правилу они поставлены?

**"Теперь, прочитавшие эту тему, стали немножечко грамотнее".**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

• Чтобы понять, нужны или не нужны запятые, необходимо в первую очередь найти подлежащее и сказуемое.
Главные члены: *прочитавшие* (что сделали?) *стали грамотнее* (или наоборот: стали грамотнее (**кто?**) прочитавшие). Подлежащим является [субстантивированное](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) причастие *прочитавшие*, перешедшее в разряд имён существительных.

В этом предложении нет *никаких* оборотов, поэтому пишем без запятых.
*Теперь прочитавшие эту тему стали немножечко грамотнее*.
[Классика: Поднявший меч от меча и погибнет.]

Примеры:
*Об «Озе» было много разговоров, **прочитавшие** поэму свысока **поглядывали** на нас, невежд, и бесконечно **цитировали** поэму* (И. Н. Вирабов. Андрей Вознесенский);
***Прочитавшие** ее **возьмутся** за стихи, а здесь не все так однозначно* (С. Н. Есин. Дневник).

• А вот в этом предложении запятые нужны:
*Теперь люди* (студенты, ученики), ***прочитавшие эту тему,** стали немножечко грамотнее*.
*Люди* — подлежащее, (какие?) *прочитавшие эту тему* — причастный оборот, стоящий после определяемого (главного) слова.

Примеры:
*Эту заметку о самом себе я упрячу очень далеко, так как люди, **прочитавшие ее,** сделают глупые выводы и примутся сплетничать* (Ирина Добрушина. Миниатюры);
*Мы были самые современные молодые люди, **прочитавшие самую современную книгу,** описавшую именно нашу жизнь, и ничью другую* (Андрей Битов. Как читали 30 лет назад).